# How to fix this regex for PHP 7.2 to avoid PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR?

Tags: php, regex, php-7, preg-replace-callback

I am moving some code (that I inherited) from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.2. The following preg_replace_callback fails with preg_last_error of PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR, and returns an empty string. This happens when the subject string gets beyond a certain length:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback( "/\?>((.|\n)*?)<\?(php)?/","eval_mixed_helper",$string,-1,$count);
```

I found a few discussions on this. If I use ini_set('pcre.jit', false); the problem goes away, but I'm not sure that is the best solution.

I'm no regex expert by any means, so I wonder how the pattern in the preg_replace_callback could be improved to avoid this overflow. I think what it does is match any chunk of html between a php end tag and the next php start tag.

I also tried:

```
"/\?>((.)*?)<\?(php)?/s"
```

...which may get a little further but still fails.

Comment: `(.|\n)*?` causes it. Replace with `(?s:.*?)`. Or `"/\?>(.*?)<\?(php)?/s"`

Comment: Thank you! The first one doesn't seem to work (generates an error) but the second one does.

Comment: I would also say that this question is different from the linked one, in that I was specifically asking for help with this specific regex, and the other question, while related to the same issue, does not provide a specific solution to this question.